# Does Mathematica have an equivalent to the Python 'translate' function?

Tags: string-manipulation, character-encoding

In Python you can make a character translation table with 'maketrans', passing it two strings of the same length. Then you can call 'translate' passing a new string and the table you just created. The function will map characters in the input string using the table you created with 'maketrans'.

Is there an easy way to do this in Mathematica without using a long list of rules or an Association?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

maketrans[str1_String, str2_String] :=
 Rule @@@ Thread[Characters /@ {str1, str2}] /;
  Equal @@ (StringLength /@ {str1, str2})

alphabet = CharacterRange["a", "z"];

str1 = StringJoin@alphabet;

SeedRandom[1234];

str2 = StringJoin@RandomSample[alphabet];

rules = maketrans[str1, str2];

garble = StringReplace["this is an example", rules]

(* "krex ex bi znbcthz"  *)
```

Undo translation

```
StringReplace[garble, Reverse /@ rules]

(* "this is an example" *)
```

Comment: Nicely done! I was hoping for some Mathematica builtin function that would do the work of maketrans, but this is a very nice solution, although it ultimately involves "a long list of rules" (see problem statement).

Comment: The list of rules is "the table". The form of the table is immaterial; you are still just doing a form of table lookup.

Answer (score 12):

[Python String maketrans() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_ref_string_translate3)

Python code:

```
txt = "Hi Sam!"

x = "mSa"
y = "eJo"

mytable = txt.maketrans(x, y)

print(txt.translate(mytable))
```

Mathematica code:

```
txt = "Hi Sam!"

x = "mSa";
y = "eJo";

StringReplace[txt, Thread[Characters /@ (x -> y)]]

Clear[x, y, txt]

(* "Hi Sam!" *)
(* "Hi Joe!" *)
```